# Cloudformation Stack can't be deleted because of Circular reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I can't delete a stack in cloud formation because some how, I have created a circular reference between the Output and itself through using the CDK.

Every attempt I make to remove the output or delete the stack I get `Export the-role cannot be deleted as it is in use by the-stack`

```
"Outputs": {
        "TheRole": {
            "Description": "Role ARN",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::ImportValue": "the-role"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": "the-role"
            }
        }
    },
```

The stack has no resources except CDKMetadata, which does not reference the Output.

Does anyone know of a way I can delete either the output or the stack?

Comment: Although not a great solution, have you tried deleting the role manually in IAM?

Comment: @hephalump the role doesn't exist, I even removed that from the template and deleted the actual role. It's because it's importing it's own export

Comment: Honestly think this is a broken state that I don't imagine the AWS cloudformation team would have planned for. This may require AWS support to assist, but I can't think of a way to fix this.

Comment: @WarrenG that was my conclusion too, I was hoping someone here might have an answer, as you can't get tech support on the free tier

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying issue with self-import.

I ended-up by updating the stack and replacing `{ "Fn::ImportValue": "the-role" }` by a custom string (the resolved value of "the-role" for instance).
Then, as the stack doesn't depend on the exported value, it should be possible to delete the stack.

If your are using the CloudFormation console, you can select your stack, click on the "Update" button and select "Edit template in designer" to edit and replace the CloudFormation template.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try the `DependsOn` Feature of CloudFormation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html.

Explanation: Since the role cannot be deleted as it is in use by another resource, it might work to put a `DependsOn` on the role-template meaning to first process and delete the resource and then safely remove the role since the resource does not exist anymore. After this you could then update the Stack anew.

This might be a long shot, but I would try it out.

Comment: The role was already deleted, it's the Output that I can't delete because the Output is referencing the Output - it's a circular reference.

Comment: @TheBritishAreComing Strange you were even able to create such a stack in the first place. Seems like CFN bug. Probably have to contact AWS support.